# What does 許しを乞い mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

What does 許しを乞い mean? And especially what's the role of 乞い here?
The full phrase is: まさか、また許しを乞いに参ったのではありますまいな！？

Comment: The problem is in meaning of koi - in dictionary that means 'fish', but it may also have another meaning.

Comment: That is 鯉. This is a conjugation of 乞う (also 請う).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「[乞]{こ}い」 is the [連用形]{れんようけい} (continuative form) of the verb 「乞う」.  It has absolutely nothing to do with "carp" the fish.  「乞い」 is a verb and it needs to be in that conjugation form in order to connect with the following word (another verb) 「[参]{まい}った」.

「[許]{ゆる}しを乞う」 is a set phrase meaning "to beg forgiveness".

The 「に」 here means "in order to".

***"Surely, you didn't come here to beg forgiveness again, did you?"***